# Mapping dictionary key values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have list `t=[3 ,3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0]` and it's subset as
`t_old=[3, 3, 4, 0, 0]` now I have to calculate the fequency of items which are not in t_old`( [3,1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0])`, which I have calculated`N={0:2,1:1,3:3,4:1}` but after that, I have to map these values in a list Nk of size 5 such that  `N={0:2,1:1,3:4,4:1}` so list will be `NK=[2,1,0,4,1]`
0->2,1->1,2->0 (since no frequency of 2),3->3,4->1 so `NK is[2,1,0,4,1]`
also the order is important
My code is

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import operator


t=[3 ,3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0]
t_old=[3 ,3, 4, 0, 0]
cluster=5
nr=[]
k=len(t)-len(t_old)
print("Value of k is\n",k)
z=len(t_old)
while(k):
    nr.append(t[z])
    z+=1
    k-=1

print("Value of z is\n",nr)
nr=Counter(nr)  #Counter that calculates the item that are not in t_old
print("counter is\n",nr)
d1 = dict(sorted(nr.items(), key = lambda x:x[0])) #Sorting the nr according to the key
print("Value of sorted dictonary is\n",d1)
```

So I want the output in the form of list

```
NK is[2,1,0,4,1]
```

how can I get that output pls help thanks in advance

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Can you explain further why N equals `{0:2,1:1,3:3,4:1}`? `t` has six threes, and `t_old` has two threes, so shouldn't N have four threes?

Comment: item not in t_old=[1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0] they are the items that are not in t_old.SO frequency of three is clearly 3 @kevin

Comment: I don't understand. why is `[1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0]` considered the items not in `t_old`? Why isn't it `[3, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0]`? `t_old` is five elements long, so why are we omitting the first six elements of `t`?

Comment: @Kevin he wants the difference between the `count` of items in t and t_old

Comment: @RafaelC, so you agree with me? `Counter(t) - Counter(t_old)` is `{0:2,1:1,3:4,4:1}`, not `{0:2,1:1,3:3,4:1}`

Comment: Sorrry @kevin I am wrong here it's a mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> t=[3 ,3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0]
>>> t_old=[3, 3, 4, 0, 0]
>>> N = Counter(t) - Counter(t_old)
>>> Nk = [N.get(i,0) for i in range(5)]
>>> Nk
[2, 1, 0, 4, 1]
```